# Descending order in sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

Can't seem to get my column to show in Descending order.

```
SELECT ROUND(COUNT(*) * 100.0 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employee),2)||" %" AS "% of Employee", R.Region AS Region
FROM Employee R
GROUP BY R.Region
ORDER DESC "% of Employee" DESC
```

It prints out the order of Region in DESC instead of % of employee

```
% of Employee | Region
----------------------- 
3.08%         | Darwin
20.64%        | Copley
2.44%         | Brisbane
2.44%         | Albany
```

Comment: Try ordering by `COUNT(*) DESC` instead.

Comment: Just use `ORDER BY 1 DESC`.

Comment: Your "% of employee" column is a string so anything starting with "3" will come before anything starting with "2" in descending order. Try taking the concatenation of "%" out.

Comment: @Felix Pamittan That works thanks !

Comment: `ORDER DESC "% of Employee" DESC` can never work. I guess you mean `ORDER BY "% of Employee" DESC`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're ordering on `VARCHAR`. The `Regions` being displayed in descending order is just a coincidence. You need to order by just the `COUNT(*)` instead:

```
SELECT 
    ROUND(COUNT(*) * 100.0 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employee),2)||" %" AS "% of Employee", R.Region 
    AS Region
FROM Employee R
GROUP BY R.Region
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DESC` goes at the end of the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT ROUND(COUNT(*) * 100.0 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employee),2)||" %" AS "% of Employee",
       R.Region AS Region
FROM Employee R
GROUP BY R.Region
ORDER BY "% of Employee" DESC
```